# Django Haystack Errors on certain keywords

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I use `haystack` and `whoosh` in my platform and it runs on an hourly basis indexing my content.

I have found that with certain strings it raises a

```
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [object] in u'None'
```

error.

Some of these strings include "Shoot", "Zero" and a few other ones I don't remember.

Have you encountered this before and is there a way to get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw errors like this one time. Rebuilding the index helped me.

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using external packages not coded by you since you don't sound familiar with the strings it is looking for.

I don't know anything about the packages you are using and if the keys it is looking for are essential, but the common way to deal with dictionary keys that may or may not exist is to use

```
mydict.get('keyname', defaultvalue)
```

You may need to simply file a bug report with I guess django-haystack or whatever package you are using.  You don't really say in your question.